# Is DataGrid Supported?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am trying to use a DataGrid in a Windows Phone 7 App. I haved added the following DLL's to my project

> System.Windows.Controls.Data.dll
>   System.Windows.Controls.Data.Input.dll

However, I have been told that the DataGrid control is not support on Windows Phone 7 and that the UI Guidelines say that it does not support DataGrid.

My question is:

1. Is DataGrid supported in Windows Phone 7?
2. Why do the UI Guidelines say that it does not support DataGrid?

Comment: Did you use the Silverlight DataGrid? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/2fcef606-9b50-4d4a-a2af-8ced8d5e4b2d/ you might want to take a look at this too: http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Building-a-DataGrid-Control-for-Silverlight-for-Windows-Phone-Part-1.aspx

Comment: @ctacke: why would you only edit the title? The rest of the question could have used a bit of tidying up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two questions can be answered together. The answer to question 1 basically follows from questions 2.

The datagrid can be used to easily show collections of data on a regular computer screen. The situation on a small device like a WP7 is totally different. Therefore a control like the datagrid would never be suitable for a decent phone interface. If you check out the screenshots in [this blogpost](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Building-a-DataGrid-Control-for-Silverlight-for-Windows-Phone-Part-1.aspx) you should notice that it just does not fit in. This is especially true for the WP7 design style.

If you want good advice on how to replace the datagrid with something suitable you can post a questions with the data you want to show and people will be able to give you advice on how you should design your UI.

Comment: Thank you , very much for the response. As of now i am Pleased with the look of DataGrid in my Windows Phone 7 App , i have a question:- if we use dataGrid will it create a problem when the app is being certified?????????????????????? if we use datagrid is it against the UI guidelines of app certification??????

Answer (score 0):

You can use a silverlight dataGrid control for Windows Phone. Take a look at the Dev Express [Datagrid control](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/Silverlight/Grid/).